# Light Rendering Results in Low FPS

Tags: c#, xna, rendering, lightning

I am currently developing a class for my XNA game whose rendering the lights on the image. At the time, i have made the source to draw my lightmap, however, the FPS is very low in my source. I know that it is brutally reduced upon looping through each pixel, however, I do not know any other way to get & set each pixel on my Texture in XNA but using the "For" statement?

Current Source:

```
 public struct Light
    {
        public int Range;
        public int Intensity;
        public Color LightColor;
        public Vector2 LightLocation;

        public Light(int _Range, int _Intensity, Color _LightColor, Vector2 _LightLocation)
        {
            Range = _Range;
            Intensity = _Intensity;
            LightLocation = _LightLocation;
            LightColor = _LightColor;
        }
    }
    public class RenderClass
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern bool MessageBox(IntPtr h, string S, string C, int a);

        public static Texture2D RenderImage(Light[] LightLocations, Texture2D ScreenImage, Viewport v, bool ShadowBack = false)
        {
            Texture2D[] Images = new Texture2D[LightLocations.Count()];
            int curCount = 0;

            /*LOOP THROUGHT EACH LIGHT*/
            foreach (Light LightLocation in LightLocations)
            {
                /*VARIABLES*/
                Color LightColor = LightLocation.LightColor;
                int Range = LightLocation.Range;
                int Intensity = LightLocation.Intensity;

                /*GET COLORS*/
                int Width = v.Width;
                int Height = v.Height;
                Color[] Data = new Color[Width * Height];
                ScreenImage.GetData<Color>(Data);

                /*VARIABLES TO SET COLOR*/
                Color[] SetColorData = new Color[Width * Height];

                /*CIRCEL*/
                int Radius = 15 / 2; // Define range to middle [Radius]
                int Area = (int)Math.PI * (Radius * Radius);

                for (int X = 0; X < Width; X++)
                {
                    for (int Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++)
                    {
                        int Destination = X + Y * Width;

                        #region Light
                        /*GET COLOR*/
                        Color nColor = Data[Destination];

                        /*CREATE NEW COLOR*/
                        Vector2 MiddlePos = new Vector2(LightLocation.LightLocation.X + Radius, LightLocation.LightLocation.Y + Radius);
                        Vector2 CurrentLocation = new Vector2(X, Y);

                        float Distance;
                        Distance = Vector2.Distance(MiddlePos, CurrentLocation);
                        Distance *= 100;
                        Distance /= MathHelper.Clamp(Range, 0, 100);

                        Vector3 newColors = nColor.ToVector3();

                        nColor = new Color(
                            newColors.X,
                            newColors.Y,
                            newColors.Z, 
                            Distance / 100);


                        /*SET COLOR*/
                        SetColorData[Destination] = nColor; // Add to array
                        #endregion
                        #region Shadow
                        #endregion
                    }
                }


                ScreenImage.SetData<Color>(SetColorData);
                Images[curCount] = ScreenImage;
                curCount++;
            }

            return Images[0]; // Temporarily returning the first image of the array.
        }
    }
```

As you can see, this is a slow and bad method. So I was wondering, is there a better way to get & set each pixel?

Thanks in advance, dotTutorials! =)

Comment: What's the point of the `OppositeColor` delegate?

Comment: Used it earlier. My bad, I am pretty messy in this source, atm. Fixing it now =)

Comment: Perhaps you ought to clean it up; remove some of the unnecessary object creation (the Vector2 MiddlePos/CurrentLocation just to calculate distance for example) and perhaps benchmark the processing time.  I don't know if there's a more efficient method to achieve the same overall effect that you're gunning for, but if you're looping through every pixel in the rendered view, every frame, then that inner loop needs to be optimized as much as possible.

Comment: You can also move the `Clamp(Range, 0, 100)` out of the loop, and since you're multiplying Distance by 100 then later dividing by 100, you can remove those three steps.  EDIT: Also, you can move the `MiddlePos` creation out of the loop.  Anyway, optimize your loop first then you might be able to find your bottleneck.

Comment: Instead of setting each pixel on the CPU, you should draw the circles with a SpriteBatch on the GPU. Use an appropriate texture and scale. I'm sure, you can achieve the wanted result. Switch the rendertarget to the destination texture first.

Comment: True, however, I would perfer to render it. Kinda "Enlight" the area around my light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that job would be best done in a pixel shader.

You could create an Effect file that operates over one light at a time.
XNA uses DX9 so you'll be limited to 128 constant registers, which I think you can use to squeeze up to three lights.

So you set your lightmap as a render target, loop through all the lights, set the constant data on your effect, render a render-target-sized quad and in your pixel shader compute your lighting equation.

In essence something like that:

```
    // In LoadContent
RenderTarget2D lightmapRT = new RenderTarget2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice,
                                                 128,
                                                 128,
                                                 false, //No mip-mapping
                                                 SurfaceFormat.Color,
                                                 DepthFormat.Depth24);

// We now render to the lightmap in Render method
graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(lightmapRT);

// Lightmap is black by default
graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

// Use the sprite batch to draw quads with custom shader
spriteBatch.Begin(0, BlendState.Opaque, null, null, null, lightmapFx);

foreach (var light in lights)
{
    // Pass the light parameters to the shader
    lightmapFx.Parameters["Viewport"].SetValue(new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height));
    lightmapFx.Parameters["Range"].SetValue(light.Range);
    lightmapFx.Parameters["Intensity"].SetValue(light.Intensity);
    lightmapFx.Parameters["LightColor"].SetValue(light.LightColor);
    lightmapFx.Parameters["LightLocation"].SetValue(light.LightLocation);

    // Render quad
    spriteBatch.Draw(...);
}
spriteBatch.End();
```

And the FX file would look something like that:

```
float Range;
float Intensity;
float3 LightColor;
float2 LightLocation;
float2 Viewport;

struct VStoPS
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

VStoPS VS(in float4 color    : COLOR0,
          in float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0,
          in float4 position : POSITION0)
{
    VStoPS vsout = (VStoPS)0;

    // Half pixel offset for correct texel centering.
    vsout.Position.xy -= 0.5;

    // Viewport adjustment.
    vsout.Position.xy = position.xy / Viewport;
    vsout.Position.xy *= float2(2, -2);
    vsout.Position.xy -= float2(1, -1);

    // Pass texcoords as is
    vsout.TexCoord = texCoord;

    return vsout;
}

float4 PS(VStoPS psin)
{
    // Do calculations here
    // Here I just set it to white
    return float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

technique Main
{
    pass p0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PS();
    }
}
```

Note that this non-tested code and probably full of errors. I leave it up to you to figure out what needs to go in the pixel shader.